# Употребление местоимения. Ед. или мн. число?

Tags: согласование, местоимения

Во фразе — ***Пусть Ваши (Ваш) целеустремленность профессионализм и творческая энергия послужат осуществлению всех благих замыслов и начинаний*** — местоимение в ед. ч. или во мн. ч. нужно употребить? Или оба варианта допускаются?

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, пожалуйста, отметьте его [как принятый](/help/accepted-answer) (галочка рядом с ответом).

Answer (score 2):

Вариант с "ваш**и**" грамматически верен, но звучит несколько формально и потому сухо; этому способствует также "и", завершающее ряд. Более "тёплый" вариант выглядит так:

> Пусть Ваша целеустремленность, Ваш профессионализм, Ваша творческая
>   энергия послуж**а**т осуществлению всех благих замыслов и начинаний...

Здесь местоимение повторяется в вариантах, согласованных по роду с каждой желаемой сущностью. Упрощённый вариант с одним местоимением, вероятно, приемлем при согласовании *со всеми* элементами перечисления - иначе домысливание пропущенных последующих местоимений будет вызывать ощущение некоторого диссонанса.

Answer (score 1):

"Ваш" тут невозможно.

Такое местоимение (и прилагательное) пред однородными членами или перечислением может в некоторых случаях иметь форму единственного числа, но тогда уж и грамматический род надо согласовывать. По первому члену, у вас - ***Ваша целеустремленность***.

То есть разбирать стоит варианты

***"Пусть Ваши/Ваша целеустремленность, профессионализм и творческая энергия послужат осуществлению всех благих замыслов и начинаний".***

(Запятую тоже не теряем).

Какой именно вариант предпочесть? Форма единственного числа выбирается в случае, когда имеется единство членов (у нас оно относительное), но главное -

> Определение, относящееся к двум или нескольким существительным –
>   однородным членам, ставится в форме е д и н с т в е н н о г о числа:
>       1) если по смыслу сочетания ясно, что определение относится не только к ближайшему существительному, но и к последующим, например...
>   декада норвежской литературы и искусства... литературный карьеризм и
>   индивидуализм; школьная успеваемость и дисциплина... каждый завод и
>   фабрика... уличный шум и грохот; летний жар и зной...

http://rosental.virtbox.ru/styli_xliv.html#sect195.1 (параграф 195 "Определение при существительных – однородных членах")

То есть единственное число в принципе возможно, но я бы не стал рекомедовать его. Дело в том, что при наличии сказуемого во множественном числе сразу за таким перечислением подлежащих несколько усложняет понимание определения ("Ваша") как относящегося ко всему целому.

Поэтому, признавая возможность иного, я рекомендовал бы множественное число.

***Пусть Ваши целеустремленность, профессионализм и творческая энергия послужат осуществлению всех благих замыслов и начинаний. ***

Но окончательный выбор - за автором.